# Android ViewPager Indicator is not working with my gradle build setup

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using several libraries for my app, including [Jake Wharton's VPI](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Here's my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':SlidingMenu:library')
    compile project(':Android-ViewPagerIndicator:library')
    compile project(':aFileChooser:aFileChooser')
    compile project(':Crouton:library')
    compile project(':ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock')
    compile project(':ListViewAnimations:library')
    compile project(':Android-Universal-Image-Loader:library')
    compile project(':drag-sort-listview:library')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'MyMine/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['MyMine/src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['MyMine/src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['MyMine/src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['MyMine/src']
            res.srcDirs = ['MyMine/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['MyMine/assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

`settings.gradle`:

```
include ':ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock'
include ':ListViewAnimations:library'
include ':drag-sort-listview:library'
include ':Android-ViewPagerIndicator:library'
include ':Crouton:library'
include ':Android-Universal-Image-Loader:library'
include ':aFileChooser:aFileChooser'
include ':SlidingMenu:library'
```

Here's the `./gradlew build` output:

```
[...]
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl
:generateDebugBuildConfig
:mergeDebugAssets
:compileDebugRenderscript
:mergeDebugResources
:processDebugManifest
:processDebugResources
/Users/bicou/AndroidStudioProjects/MyMine/build/res/all/debug/values-v11/values.xml:76: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle'.
/Users/bicou/AndroidStudioProjects/MyMine/build/res/all/debug/values-v11/values.xml:75: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'vpiTitlePageIndicatorStyle'.
/Users/bicou/AndroidStudioProjects/MyMine/build/res/all/debug/values-v11/values.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.TabPageIndicator'.
/Users/bicou/AndroidStudioProjects/MyMine/build/res/all/debug/values-v11/values.xml:81: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'footerColor'.
/Users/bicou/AndroidStudioProjects/MyMine/build/res/all/debug/values-v11/values.xml:83: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'footerIndicatorHeight'.
/Users/bicou/AndroidStudioProjects/MyMine/build/res/all/debug/values-v11/values.xml:84: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'footerIndicatorStyle'.
/Users/bicou/AndroidStudioProjects/MyMine/build/res/all/debug/values-v11/values.xml:82: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'footerLineHeight'.
/Users/bicou/AndroidStudioProjects/MyMine/build/res/all/debug/values-v11/values.xml:87: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'selectedBold'.
/Users/bicou/AndroidStudioProjects/MyMine/build/res/all/debug/values-v11/values.xml:86: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'selectedColor'.
:processDebugResources FAILED
```

As you can see it's only VPI related stuff. But they do however exist:

```
$ grep vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle Android-ViewPagerIndicator/library/res/values/*
Android-ViewPagerIndicator/library/res/values/vpi__attrs.xml:        <attr name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle" format="reference"/>
Android-ViewPagerIndicator/library/res/values/vpi__styles.xml:        <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.TabPageIndicator</item>
```

This is my `values-v11/themes.xml` file: (useless parts removed)

```
<style name="MyMineTheme.VPI" parent="MyMineTheme">
    <item name="vpiTitlePageIndicatorStyle">@style/MyMineTitlePageIndicator</item>
    <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/MyMineTabPageIndicator</item>
</style>
```

What's wrong? I've already ran `./gradlew clean && ./gradlew build`.

Something also interesting: I've had this issue for weeks with Eclipse, to make the app compile I had to run Project> Clean> All and build over again. Now that I switched to Android Studio, it's still working. But Studio is not (yet) using Gradle to build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that libraries that you use have the same parent folder name ('library' usually). You need to differ between those, so either rename it or put `archivesBaseName = 'something'` in build.gradle of your libraries.

An answer this is based can be found on
[adt google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/KE5dAjaaiA0/S5hAHdJakXoJ)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have temporarily given up on Gradle, and continued working with the old build system. As soon as the current issues are solved, I will try again to switch to gradle. Meanwhile, I changed my directory structure (and git management) to include all libraries in a common folder that is a subfolder of the main app folder, that will, I hope, ease the gradle configuration.

Comment: Also, my use case is completely covered by the `android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip` so I ended up removing the ViewPagerIndicator dependency.

Comment: I also started like this, to include all library code into my subfolder, but I think it is better to publish aar files of libraries you use to maven repository and reference them from your build.gradle file.

If you are interested I was inspired by these articles:
[publishing aar](http://www.vandalsoftware.com/post/52468430435/publishing-an-android-library-aar-to-a-maven)
[using aar](http://www.flexlabs.org/2013/06/using-local-aar-android-library-packages-in-gradle-builds)

Comment: Thanks Martin for this information. Unfortunately I have never used maven and I'm not using it for my projects. (I just learned git and try to learn gradle, I hope I won't have to learn maven aswell! :P)

Comment: You don't have to use maven for building to push .aar files to repository. Just look at the articles and there it is explained how you define a task in gradle build file to push your library to repository.

Comment: @Bicou how did you revert back to the old system from Gradle? I can't figure out how to do it, I'm absolutely sick of trying to figure this counterintuitive disaster out

Comment: I feel you. Several weeks ago I took the time to do everything step by step, it took me a day to fully figure it out and configure it with the same level of functionality as I had with the original build system. One day was lost, but now everything's fine. As per your actual question: `git checkout -- .` ;)

Answer (score -1):

I filed a bug that may be related.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=56882

Fix is to go to Settings, Compiler and uncheck Use external build.